# Django 1.11 use template from an app as admin template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, django-1.11, django-admin-actions

as the title said i am having a problem using a template in an admin view
here is my worktree

```
project
 |-- project/
 |-- myapp/
     |-- templates/
         |-- admin/
             |-- file.html
```

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapp/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

ModelAdmin.py

```
class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['export']

    def export(self,request, queryset):
        paragraphs = ['first paragraph', 'second paragraph', 'third paragraph']
        pdfkit.from_file('file.html', 'out.pdf', paragraphs)
admin.site.register(Model, ModelAdmin)
```

but i am getting "No such file: file.html" error
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the error log.

Comment: Please don't post error messages as images. Copy and paste the text.

Comment: You shouldn't need to include `myapp/templates` in `DIRS`. It will be checked by the app directories loader as long as `myapp` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 0):

`pdfkit` does not know about your `TEMPLATES` setting. You need to provide the path relative to your project directory.

```
pdfkit.from_file('myapp/templates/admin/file.html', 'out.pdf', paragraphs)
```

However this will treat the file.html as an html file. If it is a Django template that you want to render, you could use `render_to_string` and `from_string`.

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
html = render_to_string(request, 'admin/file.html', {...}) 
pdfkit.from_string(html, 'out.pdf')
```

Comment: That's not enough information. The full error message should tell you which directories Django tried which should help debug the problem. Using made up names like `myapp` and `file.html` makes it harder to help.

Comment: i ended up using html inside the modelAdmin